# Is there a faster Numpy function to do an add.at, but with two sets of indices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

I'm trying to do an operation that is pretty similar to a numpy.add.at, but with two pairs of indices, and I'm wondering if there's a faster way to do this with numpy or something else rather than a for loop, which is running pretty slowly.

The following works, but I'm trying to do it faster:

```
for x,y in indices:
  A[B[x,y]] += C[x,y]
```

where the values obtained for B[x,y] will have a lot of duplicates, so B[1,1] may be equal to B[1,2]

`numpy.add.at(A, indices, C)` is pretty close, but doesn't get me there, as B basically maps the indices into another space.  I'm hoping there's a faster way to do this with numpy or something else, probably without an explicit loop.

Comment: Are there duplicate `B` values?  If there aren't duplicates, then some version of `A[B] += C` is faster.  It's the possibility of duplicates that necessitates `add.at`.  It might also be possible to write this with `numba` and get good speed.  But others will have to help you there.  `numba's` indexing isn't quite as flexible as `numpy`.

Comment: Thanks for the question - there are many duplicate B values - I've added it to the question.  The space that indices stretches over is way bigger than the space that B maps from indices.

Comment: Consider using bincount() on B[x,y] with argument weights set to C[x,y]

Comment: @tstanisl that was it!  bincount only works in 1d it seems but I flattened the array and used it - incredible speedup thank you